# Running Springboot based application in Docker

Tags: docker

```
**FROM openjdk:8-jdk-alpine

VOLUME /tmp

COPY ./target/WebhookAPiDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war app.war

ENTRYPOINT ["JAVA","-Djava.security.egd=file:/dev/./urandom","-war","/app.war"]**
```

Above is mine Docker file for Spring Boot application.

Image build successfully, but when i try to run it, it throw some exception as given below:

> **docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec:
>   \"JAVA\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.**

Unable to understand this Error, kindly help me.

Comment: The system is case-sensitive, meaning the use of `JAVA` is incorrect. Change it to be lowercase.

Comment: I already have it as lower case but still getting kind of same error: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:367: starting container process caused: exec: "java": executable file not found in $PATH: unknown

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Josh, your comment / answer helped me resolve the issue for me

*The system is case-sensitive, meaning the use of JAVA is incorrect. Change it to be lowercase*